# Different text-decoration on links using css

Tags: html, css

I am trying to use different text-decoration on the links of each page i create in html. What i did for the first one is:

```
a
{
    color: #0033AA;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Is there any way to separate this code for every page i create? I am not asking for  solution like "use a class or id in every `<a href... >` " or "create different css files". Any ideas?

Comment: So you don't want to use IDs or classes, and don't want to use a different CSS file for each page. Why are you ruling those out and what were you expecting?

Comment: you only need to create a `class`. Not required to create another CSS file.

Comment: I know how to do it using these methods. A more general questin would be : " Can i limitate my css file using the name of my html page (something like that) or not?". Do you undestand now?

Comment: You could tie it to the body tag, if you add a class to the body tag. But CSS can't read the filename afaik

Comment: nope that not possible.

Comment: It's in the discussion phases, but not supported:  https://wiki.csswg.org/ideas/current-url-selector

Comment: I see. So there no such a way like the one i describe. Thanks for the quick responses!

Comment: @ΝίκοςΔιαμαντόγιαννης I'm not sure your requirement makes sense though. If you want it tied to specific pages, use a class/id on the body tag and then css for that name > a and apply styling. Assuming you can edit the html or any js tied to it. (js comment so you can use it to inject css)

Comment: Yeah yeah i know. Just curiosity. I post this question here in stackoverflow because here i had te only chance of getting an answer in suck a question.

Comment: @ΝίκοςΔιαμαντόγιαννης Oh, ok. Might want to mention that next time so I won't be sitting here trying to help figure out a workaround instead of if your exact solution is possible. Interesting topic though, a lot of neat tricks spawned from the question.

Comment: @JClaspill I mentioned that from the beginning that i don't search for something ordinary :)

Answer (score 2):

Something has to be different to key off of.  Put in a container div, give each container a different class then specify your links as `.container a:link` for example.

CSS:

```
.homeContainer a:link {
   color: red;
}

.aboutContainer a:link {
   color: blue;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="homeContainer">
  <p><a href="link">Link Here</a></p>
</div>

<div class="aboutContainer">
  <p><a href="link">Link Here</a></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah that's a good method. But you use classes. I am just looking for a (somehow) use of the name of my html page. Anyway thanks for your response!

Comment: That's all that's doable right now unless you load different CSS files.  So, you're out of luck.

Comment: You can use different classes into the body tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can use class :

css file :

```
a.one:link {color:#ff0000;}
a.one:visited {color:#0000ff;}
a.one:hover {color:#ffcc00;}

a.two:link {color:#ff0000;}
a.two:visited {color:#0000ff;}
a.two:hover {font-size:150%;}
```

html :

```
<a class="one" href="defaultOne.html" target="_blank">first link</a>
<a class="two" href="defaultTwo.html" target="_blank">second link</a>
```

Comment: Yeah that's a good method. But you use classes. I am just looking for a (somehow) use of the name of my html page. Anyway thanks for your response!

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want it to be url-specific? I.e. The a for cnn.com is blue and the a for espn.com is orange? Try this,

```
a[href='http://www.cnn.com'] {
    color:#0000ff;
}
a[href='http://www.espn.com'] {
    color:#ff0000;
}
```

Comment: That would style links TO specific pages, not ON specific pages.

Comment: I know about those selector.. but your solution is not quite fit with the question.

Comment: Yes- I misinterpreted his question actually, it seems he wants the css to behave differently based on which page you are on in his site, without using classes/etc or other css files.. i think?

Answer (score 0):

You can do so using nth child tricks of CSS.

```
  a:nth-child(1) {
    background: #ff0000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use jquery to do this.

```
var pathname = window.location.pathname; 
if(pathname == the_path_you_want){
  $('a').css('color','color-you-choose');
}
```

Comment: I see your point. But for now I want to find out how far can css (on it's own) go.